# Does a new socket open for every UDP connection?

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

I know that with TCP each connection creates a new socket.  Does UDP also create a new socket for each connection?

Comment: Did you mean:  *is the same true for UDP?*

Comment: The term "connection" itself isn't really appropriate for UDP.

Comment: By "connection" in reference to UDP I meant to say datagram.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

When you receive a message ([`recvmsg()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recvmsg.html)), you are told the IP address of the peer that sent the message; when you respond ([`sendmsg()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sendmsg.html)), you specify the IP address to which the message goes.  This is done over a single socket.  See also [`<sys/socket.h>`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html).

Comment: That makes sense, because we really don't have to keep any information since there's no persistent connection or retransmissions to handle.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that with TCP each connection creates a new socket.

You have that back to front. Each new socket represents a new connection.

> Does UDP also create a new socket for each connection?

That doesn't make sense either. First there are no real connections in UDP. Second, it is *you* who creates the sockets, or your application. Not UDP. Or TCP.